# Mimic `start` for npm on osx and *nix?

Tags: node.js, npm

I have a script in `package.json`,

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "start": "start npm run server && npm run build-watch"
  }
}
```

As you can see, it aim to watch the build and start a new cmd to run the server.

On windows, it works fine. But on OSX or linux, it doesn't work. Because it cannot find the command `start`.

I built [osx-start](https://npmjs.org/package/osx-start) for the OSX usage. It just mimic `start` on OSX, and you need to add `osx-start` to package.json as a dependency. For linux or unix, I may also try to mimic `start`.

The question is, is there already something can do so? If no, is this a right direction?

Comment: Shouldn't you just use `npm run server && npm run build-watch` instead of prefixing it with `start`? So `"start": "npm run server && npm run build-watch"`

Comment: @somethinghere, surely I can. But the server log and the build log will mess up together. With `start`, they just show in separated terminal.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend [concurrently](https://github.com/open-cli-tools/concurrently). You can update the script in your `package.json`

```
    "start": "concurrently \"npm run server" \"npm run build-watch\"",
```

It's not going to mess the outputs up with some prefixes of each line.
You can also specific the prefixes with `-n`, eg.

```
    "start": "concurrently -n server,build \"npm run server" \"npm run build-watch\"",
```

Another choice is [npm-run-all](https://github.com/mysticatea/npm-run-all).
Update the script of your `package.json`

```
   "start": "run-p server build-watch"
```

However, it's going to mix the outputs together.